# Align icons with text without using a negative margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm looking for a more elegant way to align the right icons with the left text vertically, as the negative margin might be a little bit of a hack.

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;
}

div.icons {
  margin-top: -1.65em;
}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>


<div class="main">
  <div class="summary">Some text</div>
  <div class="icons pull-right">
    <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
    </div>
    <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to use `display inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle`. You avoid to do things like setting negative margin which is not really good.

Comment: @Mardzis I'd add that any "magic number" are fragile because if you always have to re-set them back if you just have to refactor a small part, you'll end up doing way too much work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use a custom styles when you need:

using your code:

## Using Flexbox

support [ie10+](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex)

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="main">
  <div class="summary">Some text</div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
    </div>
    <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

## Using Table styles

support [ie8+](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Atable)

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;

  display: table;
  width: 100%;

}

div.summary {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
<div class="main">
  <div class="summary">Some text</div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
    </div>
    <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

have a look at [this flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [this guide on flexbox without flexbox](https://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox).

Also consider using more explicit class names that are not dependant to tags i.e. have a look at [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/)

Comment: Thanks! I prefer your solution with justify-content: space-between as this also lets me delete the float: right from the icons (I just have to reverse them in the html again)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. And use flex's `align` properties. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.summary {
  flex: 1;
}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>  
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="main">
  <div class="summary">Some text</div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
    </div>
    <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to set both, the icon and the text, in seperate element and then give them the following css property:

```
.mySelectors{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `flexbox` is an option, just add `display: flex` for `main` and for the `icons` this for horizontal positioning:

```
div.icons {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

and `align-items: center` for vertical alignment.

See demo below:

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.icons {
  margin-left:auto;
}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="main">
  <div class="summary">Some text</div>
  <div class="icons pull-right">
    <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
    </div>
    <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The text doesn't appear to be in the middle of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `flexbox` for doing this.

- Apply `display: flex` to parent which is `div.main` in your case
- and apply `margin-left: auto` to child which you want to align right side of window.

Something like below.

```css
div.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 14px;
  display: flex;
}

div.icons {
  margin-left: auto;
  /*margin-top: -1.65em;*/
}

div.icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  border: 0.1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 3px; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>  
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="summary">Some text</div>
      <div class="icons pull-right">
        <div class="icon fa fa-line-chart">
        </div>
        <div class="icon fa fa-bar-chart">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Flex box reference - [complete flexbox reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)